# how to count number of customer referrals?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Cust_ID . Cust_name . Cust_referred_by
1          Allan           2
2          Blake           3
3          Jen             2
4          Zeke            1
```

In this scenario Allan was referred by Blake. How do I count how many referrals each customer has?
so far I have this code:

```
select cust_name, count(cust_referred_by)
from Customer
```

I believe I have to use self join table but not sure how to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to count the cust_reffered_by for each customer, then you can use the following query:

```
select cust_name, count(cust_reffered_by)
from Customer
group by cust_name
```

What I think you want to do, is to count the number of times a customer has been referred to. You can achieve that with the following query:

```
select cust_name, count(cust_id)
from Customer
group by cust_name
```

Without more information about the semantics of the table, it's hard to be sure what you're looking for though.

Comment: In this case, cust_id is the primary key if thats what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `join` to do it

```
select a.cust_name, count(b.Cust_ID)
  from Customer a
  join Customer b on a.Cust_ID=b.Cust_referred_by
group by a.cust_name
```

Comment: @jayjayreddick can you mark my answer as accepted,please? So that others know it has been solved and do not cost time on it

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this query to get sum of one column values:

$result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Cust_referred_by) AS total FROM Customer");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$sum = $row['total'];
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    t.Cust_ID,
    t.Cust_name,
    (select count(s.Cust_ID) from Customer as s where s.Cust_referred_by = t.Cust_ID) as Referred
from Customer as t
```

You should use sub query for better versatility.
Using Group by is a very bad design, since you cannot group by two column at the same time.